# C++ BST addnote changes

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I have this simple question.
In the main function I do: `bsearch_tree bs1;` I announce on BST tree. Then I add nodes to that tree.
Then I announce on another BST tree: `bsearch_tree bs2;` and I add nodes(different) to it once again.

What it does, is adding to both tress bs1 and bs2 the same nodes.
For, when I print both trees I see that they are the same but they shouldn't be. It's wrong.

I tried to debug and found that when I add nodes it adds them to the same tree.

I somehow need to make the trees distinct.

I guess I have to make new instance of the class `bsearch_tree` but I can't change the Main function (limitation).

Here is the Header file:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class tnode
{
private:
    double data;
    tnode *left;
    tnode *right;
public:
    tnode(double key);
    friend class bsearch_tree;
    friend void assist(tnode *tmp);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream,tnode const *root);
};
class bsearch_tree
{
    tnode *root;
public:
    bsearch_tree();
    bsearch_tree(int);
    void duplicate_tree(tnode *root,tnode **new_root);
    void free_tree(tnode *node);
    void add_value(double v);
    tnode copy(tnode *root);
    bsearch_tree operator + (const bsearch_tree & t);
    bsearch_tree & operator=(const bsearch_tree & v);
    friend void print(bsearch_tree tree);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream,bsearch_tree const root);
private:
    void AddNode(double key,tnode *leaf);
    void SumTree(tnode *tree);
};
```

And here is the Code file:

```
#include<iostream>
#include "head.h"

using namespace std;

tnode::tnode(double key)
{
    this->data = key;
    this->left = NULL;
    this->right = NULL;
}

bsearch_tree::bsearch_tree()
{
    bsearch_tree *root = new bsearch_tree(NULL);
    //root = NULL;
}

bsearch_tree::bsearch_tree(int)
{
    //bsearch_tree *root = new bsearch_tree(NULL);
    root = NULL;
}

void bsearch_tree::duplicate_tree(tnode *root,tnode **new_root)
{
    if(root == NULL)
        return;
    (**new_root) = copy(root);
}

tnode bsearch_tree::copy(tnode *root)
{
    tnode* node = new tnode(root->data);
    if(root == NULL)
        return *node;
    copy(root->left);
    copy(root->right);
    return *node;
}

void bsearch_tree::free_tree(tnode *node)
{
    if(node == NULL)
        return;
    free_tree(node->left);
    free_tree(node->right);
    free(node);
}

void bsearch_tree::add_value(double v)
{
    tnode *tmp;
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        tmp = new tnode(v);
        root = tmp;
    }
    else
        AddNode(v,root);
}
void bsearch_tree::AddNode(double key,tnode *leaf)
{
    if(key >= leaf->data)
    {
        if(leaf->right != NULL)
            AddNode(key,leaf->right);
        else
        {
            tnode * n = new tnode(key);
            leaf->right = n;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(leaf->left != NULL)
            AddNode(key,leaf->left);
        else
        {
            tnode * n = new tnode(key);
            leaf->left = n;
        }
    }
}

void print(bsearch_tree tree)
{
    assist(tree.root);
}

void assist(tnode *tmp)
{
    if(tmp)
    {
        assist(tmp->left);
        cout << tmp->data << endl;
        assist(tmp->right);
    }
}

ostream & operator << (ostream & stream,bsearch_tree const root)
{
    print(root);    
    return stream;
}


bsearch_tree bsearch_tree::operator + (const bsearch_tree & t)
{
    bsearch_tree bs;
    SumTree(t.root);
    return *this;
}

void bsearch_tree::SumTree(tnode *tree)
{
    if(tree)
    {
        AddNode(tree->data,root);
        SumTree(tree->left);
        SumTree(tree->right);
    }
}

bsearch_tree & bsearch_tree::operator = (const bsearch_tree & v)
{
    if(this == &v)
        return *this;

    root = v.root;
    return *this;
}

int main()
{
  bsearch_tree bs1;

  bs1.add_value(16.0);  
  bs1.add_value(14.0);  
  bs1.add_value(6.0);  
  bs1.add_value(18.0);  
  bs1.add_value(17.0);  
  bs1.add_value(4.0);  
  bs1.add_value(5.0);  
  bs1.add_value(1.0);  
  bs1.add_value(26.0);  
  bs1.add_value(22.0);  

  cout << "bs1:" << endl;
  print(bs1);

  bsearch_tree bs2;

  bs1 = bs1 = bs1;
  bs2 = bs1;

  bs2.add_value(40.0);
  bs2.add_value(20.0);
  bs2.add_value(60.0);

  cout << "cout << bs2" << endl;
  cout << bs2;

  bsearch_tree bs3;

  //bs3 = bs1 + bs2;
  bs3 = bs1;

  cout << "cout << bs3" << endl;
  cout << bs3; 
  cin.get();
  return 0;
} // main
```

So my question is: In main function I do `bsearch_tree bs1;` and then I add some nodes to it, like this: `bs1.add_value(16.0);` then I do `bsearch_tree bs2;` and again I add some nodes to it.
Then I print both trees bs1 and bs2 and I find them equal which isn't right.

How do I make the `add_value` method to add nodes to distinct trees ?
So when I print both trees I will get different trees as the nodes I've entered are different at the first place.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear -- once for bs1 when I do: bs2.add_value(40.0); and once for bs1 when I do bs1.add_value(26.0);

Comment: `bs1 = bs1 = bs1;` ***WAT***

Comment: This main is given...It just there to check my understanding. I didn't wrote it and I can't change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `operator=` is incorrect. You're setting a root to point to the same root of the second tree. So from the point of using this operator (e.g., in `bs2 = bs1`;) both of your trees address the same shared data. You need to implement the assignment operator in a way that will create a copy of the tree data.

Comment: Right. I think you correct. So i think I should use the "new' to the root, isn't it?

Comment: Yea, screw destructors, who cares about memory leaks... <sniff>

Comment: @MaD If you want a copy, you need to use some allocation mechanism, such as `new`. You also don't release the allocated memory - add destructor. And you're also mixing `new` and `free` in the code. Don't. Use `new` with `delete` or `malloc` with `free`.

Comment: @Bartek Banachewicz it's still work in progress and I try to solve first the mistakes that I already have. The finalization of the code will be as soon as I've solved the problems.

Comment: @icepack thanks for the advice. I will get to it. As I said it's still work in progress and many things are left for now. I'm trying to solve the operator= issue right now. Thanks once again.